# CAayer - (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx is never called

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I have trying to draw using CALayer through subclassing . I know there are some posts regarding i have seen most of them and followed the solutions give but no success. like setting the frame size. Here is the code. Need some help thx in advance

```
//
//  NewView.m
//  layerPractise


#import "NewView.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
#import "NewLayer.h"
#import "NewLayer2.h"

@interface NewView() {
//  NSMutableArray *_normalizedValues;

}
@end

@implementation NewView
@synthesize _containerLayer;

@synthesize layer,shouldAddNewLayer;

-(void)doInitialSetup {
    self._containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [_containerLayer setFrame:self.frame];
    [self.layer addSublayer:self._containerLayer];
//    [_containerLayer retain];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self doInitialSetup];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self doInitialSetup];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)addCustomLayer{



    NewLayer *newLayer = [NewLayer layer];

    newLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    [_containerLayer addSublayer:newLayer];
    [newLayer setNeedsDisplay];


}



// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

//- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
//{
//    // Drawing code
//}


@end
```

and the NewLayer class

```
- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer{

    self = [super initWithLayer:layer];
    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
        self.delegate = self;
        CGRect r = self.frame;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    return self;
}

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {

    [super needsDisplayForKey:key];

}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 500, 800);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addCustomLayer` method never gets called. In `doInitialSetup` a layer gets created but its type is `CALayer` and not your custom subclass `NewLayer`.